# AngularJS - How to ignore debounce when submitting form?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form that updates an other field when the first field gets updated. The other field is updated after some delay on the change event, as specified with the `debounce` entry in the `ng-model-options` attributes.

My problem is that I would like the other field to get updated as soon as possible (ie. with a 0 delay) when the form is submitted, including when the Enter key is pressed while typing in the first field.

Currently, when typing fast and pressing Enter, the duplicated field doesn't get submitted with the latest value because of the `change` delay, and despite the `submit` delay I tried to use.

How can I update the duplicated field value as soon as possible when the Enter key is pressed, just before the form gets submitted?

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          ng-model="yourName"
          ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit default', debounce: { submit: 0, default: 2000 } }"
          placeholder="Enter a name here"
        >
      </div>
      
      <hr>
      
      <div>
        <label>Duplicated field:</label>
        <input name="duplicatedField" type="text" ng-value="yourName">
      </div>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit. It should compensate for any debouncing you have on ng-model.

You could also submit yourName directly as the other part of your post. Or does the duplicated field have different data to the yourName when it updates? That way the duplicated field is just for show on the front and you should always submit the correct yourName.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know what I could do with ngSubmit... What would be the expression to use in the ngSubmit directive on the `form` tag?

My example is over simplified compared to my real need (but shows indeed my problem in a simple way), that's why I don't submit yourName directly.

Comment: How is your POST working at the moment? Is there a function in your controller that you're calling? Ideally you'll make a function that handles your post in the controller, and put the name of that method in the ngSummit. Something like - <form ng-submit="myPostFunction(myObj)">. Does that make sense?

Comment: My POST is working very simply, it is a pure HTML one, so I don't have a ngSubmit directive handled by a AngularJS controller. Maybe I should try this and see if it magically updates data before submitting the form.
I found an other solution to my problem, so I am wondering if I close this question, but it could be useful to know how to force refresh bindings on a submit event.

Comment: Ah okay, I don't know about handling a POST that way. Close the question if you want. Ng-submit and such are all on the angular website anyway.